# Cribbage Peg Slot Metal Slider/Cover?

Tags: materials

I am making a cribbage game board and need assistance finding the best way to create or find the peg slot metal slider or cover.

I have been looking for the metal slides to cover the peg board slot on cherry board with no luck.  Anyone know where can I find those or ideas for a similar sort of cover?

Comment: I put the details into the body of the question. No one really reads the title for content.

Comment: Don't forget that you can do a lot of research with little effort: a web search for "woodworking cribbage board" will certainly show you what others have done and maybe give you ideas for your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Have been looking for the metal slides to cover the peg board slot on the board I made out of cherry.

Cribbage boards come in a huge variety of styles (consider [this large-mouth bass board](https://www.cribbagesupply.com/3dlabacrbo.html)), and I don't recall seeing two that had the exact same peg storage covers, so I think you'll have a hard time sourcing those covers as a separate part. Since you probably just need one or two, I think your best bet is to make your own. [McMaster-Carr](https://www.mcmaster.com) is a good source for all sorts of metal stock, but look around your house or your local big box store for candidates: the blade of an old butter knife or spatula might make good raw material.

Comment: *"Cribbage boards come in a huge variety of styles"* man you ain't kidding, I just Googled and !, I had no idea. Re. your suggestions for useful stock around the house (extra +1 for that if I could BTW) do these covers typically require any holes drilled in them? If so that presents a difficulty as stainless can be found to be difficult to impossible to drill successfully.